# SDL Audio - Plays only Static Noise

Tags: c, audio, ffmpeg, sdl

Im having an issue with playing audio.

Im new to the SDL World of things so im learning from a tutorial.

http://dranger.com/ffmpeg/tutorial03.html

As far as audio goes, i have exactly what he put down and didnt get the result he says I should get. In the end of the lesson he specifies that the audio should play normally. However all i get is excessively loud static noise. This leads me to believe that the packets arent being read correctly. However I have no idea how to debug or look for the issue.

Here is my main loop for parsing the packets:

```
 while (av_read_frame(pFormatCtx, &packet) >= 0) {

         if (packet.stream_index == videoStream) {
             avcodec_decode_video2(pCodecCtx, pFrame, &frameFinished, &packet);

             if (frameFinished){

                 AVPicture pict;

                 pict.data[0] = yPlane;
                 pict.data[1] = uPlane;
                 pict.data[2] = vPlane;
                 pict.linesize[0] = pCodecCtx->width;
                 pict.linesize[1] = uvPitch;
                 pict.linesize[2] = uvPitch;

                 sws_scale(sws_ctx,
                     pFrame->data, pFrame->linesize,
                     0, pCodecCtx->height,
                     pict.data, pict.linesize);

                 //SDL_UnlockTexture(bmp);

                 SDL_UpdateYUVTexture(bmp, 0, 
                     yPlane, pCodecCtx->width, 
                     uPlane, uvPitch, 
                     vPlane, uvPitch);


                 SDL_RenderClear(renderer);
                 SDL_RenderCopy(renderer, bmp, NULL, NULL);
                 SDL_RenderPresent(renderer);


                 av_free_packet(&packet);


             }

         }
         else if (packet.stream_index == audioStream) { 
             packet_queue_put(&audioq, &packet);

         }
         else
             av_free_packet(&packet);



         SDL_PollEvent(&event);

         switch (event.type) {
         case SDL_QUIT:
             quit = 1;
             SDL_DestroyTexture(bmp);
             SDL_DestroyRenderer(renderer);
             SDL_DestroyWindow(screen);
             SDL_Quit();
             exit(0);
             break;
         default:
             break;

         }

     }
```

this is my initialization of the audio device :

```
aCodecCtxOrig = pFormatCtx->streams[audioStream]->codec;
    aCodec = avcodec_find_decoder(aCodecCtxOrig->codec_id);
    if (!aCodec) {
        fprintf(stderr, "Unsupported codec!\n");
        return -1;
    }

    // Copy context
    aCodecCtx = avcodec_alloc_context3(aCodec);
    if (avcodec_copy_context(aCodecCtx, aCodecCtxOrig) != 0) {
        fprintf(stderr, "Couldn't copy codec context");
        return -1; // Error copying codec context
    }


    wanted_spec.freq = aCodecCtx->sample_rate;
    wanted_spec.format = AUDIO_U16SYS;
    wanted_spec.channels = aCodecCtx->channels;
    wanted_spec.silence = 0;
    wanted_spec.samples = SDL_AUDIO_BUFFER_SIZE;
    wanted_spec.callback = audio_callback;
    wanted_spec.userdata = aCodecCtx;


    if (SDL_OpenAudio( &wanted_spec, &spec) < 0) {
        fprintf(stderr, "SDL_OpenAudio: %s\n", SDL_GetError());
        return -1;
    }

    avcodec_open2(aCodecCtx, aCodec, NULL);

    // audio_st = pFormatCtx->streams[index]
    packet_queue_init(&audioq);
    SDL_PauseAudio(0);
```

The Call back (same as the tutorial):|

```
void audio_callback(void *userdata, Uint8 *stream, int len) {

    AVCodecContext *aCodecCtx = (AVCodecContext *)userdata;
    int len1, audio_size;

    static uint8_t audio_buf[(MAX_AUDIO_FRAME_SIZE * 3) / 2];
    static unsigned int audio_buf_size = 0;
    static unsigned int audio_buf_index = 0;

    while (len > 0) {
        if (audio_buf_index >= audio_buf_size) {
            /* We have already sent all our data; get more */
            audio_size = audio_decode_frame(aCodecCtx, audio_buf, sizeof(audio_buf));
            if (audio_size < 0) {
                /* If error, output silence */
                audio_buf_size = 1024; // arbitrary?
                memset(audio_buf, 0, audio_buf_size);
            }
            else {
                audio_buf_size = audio_size;
            }
            audio_buf_index = 0;
        }
        len1 = audio_buf_size - audio_buf_index;
        if (len1 > len)
            len1 = len;
        memcpy(stream, (uint8_t *)audio_buf + audio_buf_index, len1);
        len -= len1;
        stream += len1;
        audio_buf_index += len1;
    }
}
```

Comment: Just a friendly tip, you could make it much easier for us to help, if you could provide a [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve). Especially referring to the minimal part. Try taking out the code that isn't necessary to demonstrate the problem you're having. Your question becomes much easier to answer once you've removed the unnecessary code.

Comment: That's my generic, "this question could be better if shortened" comment. But here's my not so generic comment. This isn't going to be easy to debug, especially since you're just learning the material, and especially hard for us since there is so much code to go through. If possible, any effort by you would be appreciated to debug. Try to change some parameters around, or try to remove as much code as possible to get the same results.

Comment: My Apologies, thanks for the tip

Answer (score 0):

I also had same problem when I learn tutorial 3. The comments by pprahul in https://github.com/mpenkov/ffmpeg-tutorial/issues/11 solve my problem when playing .MPG file with mp2 format audio. But the problem still occur when I play .MP4 file with AAC format audio.

A snapshot of that comment is to set the decode format manually， by

```
//after get the AVCodecContext *codecCtx(aCodecCtx in tutorial).

if (codecCtx->sample_fmt == AV_SAMPLE_FMT_S16P) {
    codecCtx->request_sample_fmt = AV_SAMPLE_FMT_S16;
}

//...
```

It seems that the problem will not occur with early version of FFmpeg (1.01 and below).